# Use regex to replace a specific pattern

Tags: java, regex

From a given string, am trying to replace a pattern such as "sometext.othertext.lasttext" with "lasttext". Is this possible in Java with Regex replace? If yes, how? Thanks in advance.

I tried

```
"hellow.world".replaceAll("(.*)\\.(.*)", "$2")
```

which results in world. But, I want to replace any such arbitrary sequence. For instance com.google.code should be replace with code and com.facebook should be replaced with facebook.

Just to add, a test input is: 
***if (com.google.code) then*** 
and the test output should be:
***if (code) then***

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far? What didn't work? Did you get errors?

Comment: [Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: My knowledge is from [here] http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm. I don't get how to mention a pattern such as last item.

Comment: If the format you provided as example is constant, could you use String.split() and grab the last resultant element?

Comment: I try "hellow.world".replaceAll("(.*)\\.(.*)", "$2") and it works to give world as output. But, the problem I have is w.x.y.z should lead to z. Something like, I wish to just get the classname out of fully qualified java class name (just for example). Thanks.

Comment: @IdusOrtus, I believe String.split is inelegant and even to use it I have to tokenize the entire text or grab all the patterns of x.y or w.x.y or such sort. I thought, there must be an easy way with regex patterns. My input text is relatively short (like a max of 1000 words).

Comment: Let's give a clue: `"(.*)\\.(.*)", "$2"` first `(.*)` is the first capture group. `\\.` would match a litteral dot. second `(.*)` is the second capture group and `$2` refers to it. I'll let you exercise [HERE](http://regex101.com) with regexes to understand them better and extend the exemple :) (tip: `$` means end of line in regex)

Comment: Try declaring a String array, assign the return value of yourStringName.split(".); to it and grab the last element of the array. Split() uses regex Pattern / Matcher behind the scenes. Check the API for String if you need more examples.

Comment: @Tensibai, I understood how my code works. It will be helpful if you can point me to some sources where there are examples that demonstrate how to backreference any arbitrary number of groups. Thanks.

Comment: @VenkateshV See [THIS](http://regex101.com/r/vJ2bN9/2) and read the panel on the right for the explanation.

Comment: @IdusOrtus, Thanks! I understand how to implement using split. I will still like to know if there is a one line solution using regex to do the same. If there is not, I will resort to split.

Comment: @Tensibai, Your suggestion is very close to what I need. But, I still seem to be at some loss. The pattern is removing everything in the line. For instance, I expect "if (d)" for an input of "if (a.b.c.d)". So, I replaced my regex to "([a-z][a-z)*)\\.([a-z][a-z]*) and use $2 but this does not seem to work.

Comment: @VenkateshV read a little about regex, you obvisouly don't understand them. When I say that `$` mean end of line and I give a you a link explaining in detail each part of the regex , If you don't follow the advice to read the right panel, you won't learn ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for,  if you're trying to avoid String methods. It can be made more succinct, but I'm hoping this will give you a better understanding.

As others suggested, String methods are cleaner.

```
class Split {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String inputString = "if (com.google.code) then";
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile("((?<=\\()[^}]*(?=\\)))"); // Find text within parenthesis
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(\\))"); // Find last portion of text between . and )

        Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(inputString);
        String in2 = "";
        if (m2.find())
            in2=m2.group(1); // else ... error checking
        inputString = m.replaceAll(in2); // do whatcha need to do
    }
}
```

If the parenthesis aren't the concern, use this.

```
class Split {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String in = "if (com.google.code) then";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(\\))");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
        if(m.find()) 
            in = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(in); // or whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
str.replaceAll(".*\\.(\\w+)$", "$1")
```

Explanation [here](http://regex101.com/r/rR7vH3/1)

Comment: This does not work for me.  A test input: if (com.google.code) then Expected test output: if (code) then

Comment: Please post your code, because for me works correctly. Maybe you're comparing strings like `if(replaceReturn == "code")`, and it's not appropriate in Java.

Comment: My test code is same what IdusOrtus has put in his post above. Of course, I could not figure out the correct pattern. His solution works for me.